# Flex performance hit?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I looked at this demo:
http://bubblemark.com/

Flex seems very slow compared to silverlight 3. Unfortunately can't see pure flash but should flex be forbidden if performance is top requirements compared to Flash ?

Comment: -1 and a vote to close.  There are lots of issues that may affect performance of an app.  You seem to be looking for a universal answer based on a single sample.  You won't find a correct answer in that case.

Comment: Your answer and vote is biased. You promote your site on flex.

Comment: @user310291 I didn't provide an answer to this question. That said please read the Stack Overflow FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq and this blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ .  Many different factors come into play on performance issues.  The answer to your question is "It depends"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gosh... If I were to make an app like that, why would I incur the penalty of the Flex layer?  To me, Flex is not the right development stack for that app... but Flash might be.  I'd be curious to see how it works directly using the Flash API without the overhead of Flex controls and libraries?

I guess my point is: most Flex applications are not animations like that.  Flex is really good as an application development stack.  Silverlight is too, for that matter.  The performance overhead that Flex incurs for most applications you might build is small enough that it isn't noticed by the user.

That being said, it really depends on the type of app you are developing.  Pretty UIs over data services, which is a huge percentage of Flex apps, is what Flex does best IMO.  In other words, I wouldn't develop Angry Birds in Flex.  It wasn't built for that type of app.  BUT, when Flex is good at something, it is really good at it.  The productivity gain is certainly worth it to me when compared to performance hit that is negligible for most Flex apps I build.

Just for the record, everything I am saying here about Flex is also true of Silverlight, IMO.  It is just that with Silverlight, there is no distinction between the animation layer and the application layer... it is not broken into two layers like Flash/Flex is.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is your top requirement, you shouldn't be writing for the Flash VM. ;)

The flex framework adds a lot of stuff that can go slowly, and coding without it will certainly give you a performance advantage.  However, it will also cripple you by removing all the nice UI stuff that's part of flex.  You'll have to do some tests for your particular application and see if the performance gain is worth the loss of ease of coding.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't take that test as a benchmark.

If you try the same test on different browsers, it might give you a different result. (I got better fps on flex then on silverlight using firefox, also when going to the back button of the browser and waiting a bit would slow down silverlight.)

As Kelsey Rider said, do some tests for your particular app and try use the average setup of your target group.